# Project runs, but can't see files in Dev-C++

Tags: c++, file, ide, dev-c++

I recently was working on a project in Dev-C++, then saved it. When I opened the project today, I couldn't see any of project files. The project still runs correctly. Is there any way to access my code to edit it?

Answer (score 0):

if you can still compile it, be sure you are watching into label with Project and not debugging or something else

if you are not able to compile your project
you can add your files again into your project 
they are still in your directory